# How do I make a striped v-data-table in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a table

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="bookings"
  class="elevation-1"
  :search="search"
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <td>{{ props.item.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ props.item.time }}</td>
    <td>{{ props.item.vehicle }}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Made in Vuetify, It works all fine, I just need to make alternate rows into different colors. Or the give the bootstrap `.table-striped` class to the table.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could achieve that by using the following CSS rule :

```
tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
 }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Carbs (g)',
          value: 'carbs'
        },
        {
          text: 'Protein (g)',
          value: 'protein'
        },
        {
          text: 'Iron (%)',
          value: 'iron'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%'
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1">
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are putting this in the script tag. Make sure you remove `scoped`

Comment: @bhaskar Do you have any explanation why `scope` doesn't work this case?

Comment: That's because the v-table is a component imported from Vuetify (global import). Thus 'scoped' prevents the classes from being applied to the imported component. @Duy Tran

Comment: How do I make table striped on mobile version?

Comment: @TriMueriSandes I think you need something like `tr td:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); }`

Comment: Yeah I did it, but just work on desktop only, Please help me, I need table striped on mobile version

Comment: please provide an example in codepen and the desired result

Comment: Finally, for my case I just disable mobile breakpoint v-data-table with code <v-data-table :mobile-breakpoint="0" />

Answer (score 9):

Expanding Boussadjra Brahim's answer.
Here is some css for styling the header and footer globally

```css
<style>
  tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: rgba(236, 237, 237);
  }

  tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(250 ,250, 250);
  }

  .v-data-table-header {
    background-color: rgba(182, 183, 187);
    color: white;
  }

  .v-data-footer {
    background-color: rgb(250 ,250, 250);
  }

  .theme--light.v-data-table thead tr th {
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This works except when I use `<style scoped>`. Any reason why ?

Comment: v-table is a component imported from Vuetify (global import). This prevents the classes from being applied to the imported component

Answer (score 9):

To achieve the stripes for both dark and light theme I do this:

```
<style>
.theme--light.v-data-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
}
.theme--dark.v-data-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had some trouble with this if you have a table which is expandable.
This is because following the example at vuetify documentation, the resulting table will make one row also for the expanding content, which is hidden I think.

Anyhu this is the style I ended up with:

```
tr:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

Every forth row, with a offset of 3, so you dont include the header.

Answer (score 4):

In `v-data-table class="elevation-1"` I changed `class` property to `class="table-striped elevation-1"` and it works fine to me.

Comment: this does not work since there's no class called `table-striped`

Comment: Referencing OP, it appears they're using Bootstrap (not super clear, but I'm assuming), which means `table-striped` would exist and work in that case. But if you're explicitly using Vuetify alone, it won't work.

Comment: @GlenDespauxJr ftom the edit history of the question, you can see that someone added tags and modified the title to be able to answer about vuetify, while the OP asked about boostrap

Answer (score 0):

I use [material design color](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#material-colors) for the background like this css style:

```
<style>
tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    /* 'teal lighten-5' basides on material design color */
    background-color: #E0F2F1;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    /* 'deep-orange lighten-5' basides on material design color */
    background-color: #FBE9E7;
}
</style>
```

The results can be seen as below:
[image]
Thanks to Boussadjra Brahim for helping answer this question. This answer is inspired by his answer.