# How to display rows in Vue.js with different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm not front-end developer so Vue and JS are new for me. I'm writting application to managing sales.

In one of the components, I'd like to display invoices as a list. To make better look of those rows, I've come with idea to make one row white, next grey, next white, next grey and so on.

And here is my question: how to do that in Vue?

I tried something like that, but it doesn't work (I just deleted li items, because those are useless for that example):

```
<li v-for="fruit in fruits" v-bind:key="fruit.id" :style="{backgroundColor: color}" v-bind="counter++"> 
</li>
```

and here is my Vue instance:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            color: '',
            counter: 0,
            fruits: ["Lorem isum", "Lorem isum", "Lorem isum", "Lorem isum"]

        }
    }, methods: {
        choseColor() {
            if (this.counter % 2 !== 0 ) {
                color = 'grey'
            } else {
                color = 'white'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a striped table in vuetify v-data-table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508774/how-do-i-make-a-striped-table-in-vuetify-v-data-table) use `ul li:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Change

`:style="{backgroundColor: color}"`

to

```
:style="'background: ' + choseColor()'"
```

and

```
choseColor() {
            return ((this.counter % 2) !== 0) ? `grey` : 'white';
}
```

try it out. It should solve it.